# Script is not working on jQuery load() inside a jQuery .on event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have to make the WordPress post pages to load through AJAX because I think that is a hassle on the user experience and one more things is I don't want to display: https://mydomain/dashboard/page/2 on the URL. Here is the things:

Everything seems to load perfectly through AJAX with the use of this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("body").on('click', '.job-page a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#my-jobs-content').fadeOut(0, function(){
            $("#hb_job_list").load(link + ' #hb_job_list', function() {
                $("#my-jobs-loader").hide();
                $(this).fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    $("#my-jobs-loader").show();
    });
});
```

However, there is a button on the page that is loaded that have a script and I'm not able to make it work. I tried to make the .on to .live but it returns 404 ajax error. Any tips?

Comment: I think the problem is `$(this).fadeIn(500);` where this statement is executed, `this` no longer refers to `$('#my-jobs-content')`. Try to use `$('#my-jobs-content').fadeIn(500);`.

Comment: That didn't work either @Titus, and I noticed that after the AJAX call, the script on the element is gone.

Comment: Here's a thing. I noticed that script tags are remove after the load is trigger, so I moved out the script wherein it is not affected by the container of the load.

Answer (score 0):

means the ajax cal working and you get 404 in ajax response status code ?. then probably the link var is not worked properly check the link var points to correct endpoint. since the ajax call getting triggered on click event there's is no issue using 'on' or 'live' both will work.

Comment: yeah right but the ajax call getting working in the 'on' event the event handler binding have done correctly and the possible 404 issue is in your endpoint URL  I think. try console log the endpoint and check the URL is correct